# Odd conflict between hyperref and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, luatex

Here is a code that works without loading hyperref and fails to compile (with LuaLaTeX and shell escape) when loading hyperref, even as the very last package. Here are the last lines of the output :

```
Package lastpage Warning: Rerun to get the references right on input line 60.
AED: lastpage setting LastPage
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
{
l.60 \end{document}
```

I've no idea of what is going wrong. I've read many answers here dealing with difficulties related to hyperref, but none of them worked.

```
\documentclass[11pt,svgnames, english, french]{article}

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\else
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{babel}\frenchsetup{og=«, fg=»}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,chains,fadings,fit,scopes,shapes,shadows,arrows,arrows.meta,positioning,bending,shadows.blur,shapes.misc,tikzmark,patterns,angles,quotes,spy,decorations.shapes}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{array, amsmath, bm, colortbl, enumitem, esvect, etoolbox, fancyvrb, fontawesome, fourier-otf, graphicx, icomma, ifthen, marvosym, minted, multicol, multirow, relsize, tasks, textcomp, url, xcolor, xparse, xspace}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} %%  http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html
\usepackage[autolanguage,np]{numprint}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % <<<--- UNCOMMENT TO SEE BUG !
%\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Bla

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    val/.style={circle, fill=black, text=white, text centered, font=\small\bfseries, text width=2.2ex, inner sep=.3ex, outer sep=0mm},
    link/.style={-{Latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}, shorten >=1.5ex, line width=1.5ex} }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\depth}{8}
    \node[val] (p-0-0) at (0,0) {1};
    \foreach \row in {1,...,\depth} {
        \node[val] (p-\row-0) at (0,-\row) {1};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\value}{1};
        \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
            % iterative formula : val = precval * (row-col+1)/col (+ 0.5 to bypass rounding errors)
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\value}{\value*((\row-\col+1)/\col)+0.5};
            \global\let\value=\value
            \coordinate (pos) at (\col,-\row);
            \node[val] (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {} ;
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prow}{\row-1}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pcol}{\col-1}
            \ifnum \col<\row
                \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.4]
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\opacity}{80 - 60 * abs(mod(\col-\row, 2))}
                    \draw[link, blue!\opacity!red] (p-\prow-\pcol.center) node[fill, white, circle, inner sep=1ex] {} -| node[fill, circle, inner sep=1ex] {} (p-\row-\col.center);
                \end{scope} ;
            \fi
            \pgfmathparse{\col<=\row && \row<\depth}
            \ifnum \pgfmathresult>0
                \node at ($(p-\row-\pcol)!0.5!(p-\row-\col)$) {+} ;
            \fi
            \node[val] at (pos) {\value} ; } }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the name of your macro `\value` to something else, for example to `\Value`.

Comment: Holy sh*t : it works ! Thanks. You should write an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename your macro `\value` to something else (for example `\Value` with capital V), the problem seems to be solved.

In general, it is a bad idea to use macro names for custom macros that are already used in basic TeX or LaTeX code. The macro `\value` is one of these basic macros and is used to return an integer value of a counter.

Apart from that, you should check whether you really need to load all of these packages. I reduced your example to include the macros and libraries that are really needed for your MWE (still including the `hyperref` package of course).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

Bla

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    val/.style={circle, fill=black, text=white, text centered, font=\small\bfseries, text width=2.2ex, inner sep=.3ex, outer sep=0mm},
    link/.style={-{Latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}, shorten >=1.5ex, line width=1.5ex} }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\depth}{8}
    \node[val] (p-0-0) at (0,0) {1};
    \foreach \row in {1,...,\depth} {
        \node[val] (p-\row-0) at (0,-\row) {1};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Value}{1};                      % <-- !
        \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
            % iterative formula : val = precval * (row-col+1)/col (+ 0.5 to bypass rounding errors)
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Value}{\Value*((\row-\col+1)/\col)+0.5};
            \global\let\Value=\Value
            \coordinate (pos) at (\col,-\row);
            \node[val] (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {};
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prow}{\row-1}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pcol}{\col-1}
            \ifnum \col<\row
                \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.4]
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\opacity}{80 - 60 * abs(mod(\col-\row, 2))}
                    \draw[link, blue!\opacity!red] (p-\prow-\pcol.center) node[fill, white, circle, inner sep=1ex] {} -| node[fill, circle, inner sep=1ex] {} (p-\row-\col.center);
                \end{scope} 
            \fi
            \pgfmathparse{\col<=\row && \row<\depth}
            \ifnum \pgfmathresult>0
                \node at ($(p-\row-\pcol)!0.5!(p-\row-\col)$) {+};
            \fi
            \node[val] at (pos) {\Value}; } }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I doesn't knew for the \value usage. I thought all internals of (La)TeX were odd names with @ in them.  And I need the whole set of packages because the code I pasted here is only one part of my whole code. I know there are many unwanted interactions between packages (and I am really fed up with all this mess - but LibreOffice is far worse, so I have no other choice !) so I preferred to keep the whole set.

Comment: This is fine then. I tested it with all the packages you provided originally. With "basic macros" I did not mean internal macros which indeed often have an @ in them. But for instance macros such as `\setcounter`, `\chapter`, `\parbox` etc., but also `\let` and the like, which are sometimes called user level macros, that is macros that are to be used by, for example, you. =) I think you get the idea.

Comment: Yeah, thanks ^_^ !